# Not Showing Data related to Last Date

Tags: mysql

Below is the Query

```
SELECT
users.userName,
rechannel.channelName,
trschedule.ContentType,
trprogram.programName,
trschedule.Description,
trschedule.startTime,
trschedule.endTime,
TIMEDIFF(trschedule.startTime,trschedule.endTime) AS Difference,
LENGTH(trschedule.Description) AS Charcter_Count,
ROUND( LENGTH(trschedule.Description)/6) AS Word_Count,
ROUND( LENGTH(trschedule.Description)/65) AS Line_Count,
trschedule.ProvinceName,
trschedule.CityName,
trschedule.AreaName,
trschedule.ContentTone,
trschedule.searchText,
trschedule.CountryName,
trschedule.transmissionDate,
trschedule.insDate
FROM users 
Inner Join trschedule ON users.userID = trschedule.insertID 
Inner Join rechannel ON rechannel.channelID = trschedule.channelID 
Inner Join trprogram ON trprogram.programID = trschedule.programID
WHERE (trschedule.insDate BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-12')
```

But the result is showing from (insertDate)2012-10-01 to 2012-10-11 not showing the data of 2012-10-12.

What is the reason any idea???/

Comment: What is the data type of your `trschedule.insDate` column?  If it's a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` type, you should strip the time part by using MySQL's [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function: `WHERE DATE(trschedule.insDate) BETWEEN ...`.  Otherwise your date `2012-10-12` is cast to the `DATETIME` value `2012-10-12 00:00:00` and any times later than that on the same day will be outside of the given range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, just change the last line:

```
WHERE (DATE(trschedule.insDate) BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-12')
```

Comment: Issue is with `insDate` not with string date casting. Wait for OP answer comments.

Comment: bro this is not related to string date casting... its related to datetime to date casting. in the absence of DATE cast your sequel is treated as `BETWEEN '2012-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-12 00:00:00' which includes a maximum timestamp of midnight of 12 and not the entire day.

Comment: I think you'd rather want to do the `DATE` on the `insDate` column and not the literals

Comment: ah!!my bad.. yes you are right.. you should put the DATE on insDate. I've made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not specified the time component of the date, mySQL is treating '2012-10-12' as the midnight between '2012-10-11' and '2012-10-12'.

Try replacing the between with :

`trschedule.insDate >= '2012-10-01' AND trschedule.insDate < '2012-10-13'`

Comment: Issue is with `insDate` not with string date casting. Wait for OP answer comments.

Comment: This would also include records with the timestamp '2012-10-13 00:00:00' i.e exactly the midnight of 13 and that one might not want

Comment: @mickeymoon no it wouldn't, i used `<` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 1):

Or try this:

```
WHERE (trschedule.insDate BETWEEN '2012-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-12 23:59:59')
```

Comment: you should better try this one(of the my two answers) because in the previous case any indexes on insDate wouldn't be picked due to date function.